# How to obtain all the security identifiers (SID) that match a Windows user?

Tags: .net, windows, active-directory, sid

Using .NET, I would like to programmatically get a list of all the groups for which a Windows user is a member as well as all other SID (Security identifiers) that represent a logged in user. The resulting list should contain:

1. The user himself.
2. The groups for which he is a direct member
3. The nested groups for which he is an indirect user
4. The [WellKnownSidType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype.aspx)s that match. For example:

   - Everyone
   - NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
   - ...

The first item is trivial and I can already retrieve points 2 and 3 by using `System.DirectoryServices` and the attribute `tokenGroups` on the `DirectoryEntry` representing my user like [this example](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Determining_User_Group_Membership_in_Active_Directory_and_ADAM).

Can somebody find an (easy) way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an easy way, I would say [UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx) is really easy.  The only thing is that you can find it only in .NET 3.5 or later.

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "YourUser"))
    {
        foreach (Principal p in user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
        {
             Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
    }
 }
```

`GetAuthorizationGroups` returns you all the nested groups, including the Well known SID.  It tries different ways of retrieving the nested group information.  Indeed, one of the approaches it used is to use `DirectoryEntry` to access `tokenGroups` attribute.

**UPDATE**

To check whether the current user is in `NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE` or `LOCAL`, we can use `WindowsIdentity.Groups`, which retrieves the current logon token directly.  Note that the membership of `NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE` and `LOCAL` are determined at runtime.  The user is assigned to these groups based on the fact that you are logging onto that system now.  Similarly, on my Windows 7, I can see my current logon user is also a member of `NT AUTHORITY\REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON` because I was logging on via remote desktop.

```
 WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
 foreach (var group in id.Groups)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(((NTAccount)group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount))).Value);
 }
```

I am sorry that I don't know any way to get the `NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE` membership for *any* arbitrary users.  I suspect there is no such way because this type of group membership is determined at the runtime only when that user is really logging on.

Comment: Thanks Harvey, your solutions contains almost everything. It is still missing some SIDs though (LOCAL, CONSOLE LOGON, NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE...) I still don<t know if I will need them though. Any idea on how to get those?

Comment: Thanks Harvey, your example and explanations were more than perfect.